# Apache directory authentication against ldap groups

Tags: apache, authentication, httpd.conf

I'm using *Apache 2.2.15* and I need a specified directory to authenticate against one of three LDAP groups. For example, I want that directory to be able to authenticate against either Group1, Group2, or Group3. If a user has one of these groups associated with their LDAP accounts then they should be able to access the content within this directory. In my *Httpd.conf* file I have the following block of code:

```
<Directory /path/to/folder>
    AuthName                 "Name of Authentication"
    AuthType                 Basic
    PerlSetVar BaseDN        dc=abc, dc=def, dc=ghi
    PerlSetVar LDAPServer    nameofldapserver
    PerlSetVar UIDAttr       uid
    PerlSetVar AuthGroup     (want this somehow be 3 groups)
    PerlSetVar CookieName    nameofcookie
    PerlSetVar SessionsDB    /path/to/sessions
    PerlAuthenHandler        Auth::Authldaphandler
    require valid-user
</Directory>
```

I've tried adding three groups in one line for AuthGroup but had no luck. I also created multiple declarations of AuthGroup to see if it would do anything, but also no luck. Any ideas on how to make this directory authenticate against one of the listed groups?